# How to generate xls & xlsx from office 2003 xml spreadsheet programatically in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Currently our application exporting large data to office 2003 xml spreadsheet format in server.
The user can download the xml file.The file can be easily opened in office 03 and 07 correctly.
I want to know whether it is possible to create xls and xlsx format from this xml file in server and serve them to user?

[The server doesn't have office and neither will be.So interop is useless in this case.]

====== EDIT=====

Can't use third party solutions... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question corretly, you are not just serving 'pure' XML, but SpreadsheetML that is interpreted by Excel just as an ordinary Excel-file in binary format. So your users already have a very nice solution. How do are you creating those files? I use an XSLT to transform my XML-data to SpreadsheetML that is just a specific XML-format. In that way I can do anything that is  possible in Excel (formattings, formulas etc.). It yould be much more than just transforming XML to CSV.

Why do you want to change this? I can see that the resulting XML-Excel file usually is huge, is that the reason?

Now, since Excel 2007 format (xlsx) is basically a zip-archive of some XML-files describing the structure and the data of the file -- just rename the file extension name of any xlsx to zip and inspect after extracting -- you might be able to adapt your existing solution, i.e. instead of creating one SpreadsheetML-(XML)File create several and pack/zip them one the server. I assume your normal server installation should have the necessary tools.

BUT - this solution is difficult to maintain (as you might know wiht you current solution -- if I am at all right) and changes in the XSLT to add new functionality requires quite a bit of knowledge. So again I as well can recommend Aspose.Cells, even some knowledgeable users might be able to change simple formats.

HTH
Andreas

Comment: This will work perfectly for the XML-based format - .xlsx - but won't help you if you need to generate the .xls binary format.

Answer (score 1):

With your XML file, you could easily use XSLT to transform your XML into CSV. However, if you really need to export in native Excel spreadsheet types, it's probably a good idea to use a component.

Something we've used in the past, that I'd recommend, is [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx) – we've used this to generate Excel spreadsheets where plain CSV output wouldn't suffice (are you sure it won't suffice in your case - XSLT will make short work of that).

Whilst it's not free, it saves having to install Office on the server (and avoid using Office Automation etc.) and has very good support.

**Edited following comments**:
If you can't use third party components, if you can't install Office on the server, and you can't use interop, then – unless you want to get comfortable and read the [Excel Binary File Format (.xls) Structure Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313154%28v=office.12%29.aspx) as provided by Microsoft – the answer is a very short one: no.

Comment: The xml is not plain xml file.It already defined for microsoft excel spreadsheet format.

Comment: Then, based on your other comments suggesting that you can't use interop or install Office on the server or use third party components or software, there's no way – that I am aware of – you can convert the Office XML formats (.xlsx) into their binary counterparts. I've edited my answer above to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have office 2003 *or later) DLLs referenced to the project, I'm afraid you can't read that Office XML data in your program directly, unless of course you can manually parse the whole XML by studying its format.

Comment: i was not asking about reading.I have already generated xml according to microsoft specified format and need to save it as xls/xlsx.

Comment: Ah, OK. In that case you can .zip it as per Andrea's suggestion. If even that is not possible on your server, then I'm afraid the only solution is to send a request from your server to a web-service on a windows based server. You can create the Excel conversion logic on this new web-service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Open XML SDK to create or read xlsx files.
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5124